# Redirect to page using location header?

Tags: php, redirect

I have a function that is being run in a php file when a button is clicked on the users profile page. Once the function is complete I want the user to be redirected back to their profile page. Normally I know how to redirect but this requires including the user id to go to their specific profile. I have made the following piece of code and am attaching `err=1` at the end of it in hope to try and get a message displayed in their profile.

Hope this makes sense.

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://localhost/ptb1/profile.php?id=echo $_SESSION['user_id']err=1');
?>
```

Comment: You would need to use a double quoted string rather than a single quoted one. Vars are never interpolated in double quoted strings. Further, you would need to enclose in `{}` as `{$_SESSION['user_id']}`

Answer (score 3):

Read about [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.string.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Location: http://localhost/ptb1/profile.php?id=' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . '&err=1');
```

You also need to call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) before you try and use `$_SESSION` variables.